# URL Rewrite Apache locating files

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url rewrite that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cancun/tours/$ location-tours-listings.php?locationName=Cancun
RewriteRule ^cancun/tours$ location-tours-listings.php?locationName=Cancun
```

Problem is that now the page can't find the relative URL's, such as CSS, images, etc...

Is there a way to fix this with a command in the .htaccess file? So that when someone goes to /cancun/tours/ apache knows that it should look relative to the location-tours-listings.php file and not those other directories?

Or is the only alternative to go into the file that it is redirecting to and hard-code all of those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix it through `.htaccess`, you can add the 301 redirect to the `.htaccess` file in the root folder for each individual site, as in this example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you prefer fixing this on the browser-side, you can use the `<base>` tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML as in the following example:

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <base href="http://www.example.com" />
</head>
```

Comment: thanks, never knew the base could do something like this so I always overlooked it. Thank you

Comment: @krio: You may want to check this article for some tips on the `<base>` tag: http://www.drostdesigns.com/base-href-tag/

Comment: thanks that helps! Do you have any resources for handling spaces in apache rewrite? I have some get's that have spaces and apache is having a real problem with them

Comment: @krio: `RewriteRule ^path/with\ space.php$ /path/with_space.php [R=301,L]` Try escaping your space with a backslash "\" as in this example.

Comment: Note that changing the base URL will affect *all* relative URLs.